# Define: Play! Statelessness

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, persistence, stateless

Play's statelesness is undoubtedly one of its great advantages over more bulky, stateful alternatives. I am unable however to comprehend to what extent Play is stateless - does statelessness only concerns sessions and cookies or also all of the domain objects?

It would strike me as quite peculiar to reload all the objects in memory from persistent storage between every request, especially when several requests may concern the same objects (shared objects, or often used objects). It makes no doubt to me that one would benefit from implementing Data Source Architectural Patterns as well as Behavioural ORM Patterns (Unit of Work, Identity Map).

Hence my inquiry - to which extent is Play! truly *stateless*?